# Parse client javascript: Query to select only objectId from pointer

Tags: javascript, parse-javascript-sdk

If I have structure like below:

**_User Structure:**

```
objectId
username
password
name - string
```

**Posts Structure**:

```
objectId
postName - string
postMsg - string
postAuthor - Pointer< _User > (Pointer to the User Class)
```

I want to query post, and want to include postAuthor's objectId only.
Currently I am using something like following:

```
var Posts = Parse.Object.extend("Posts");
var query = new Parse.Query(Posts);
query.include("postAuthor");
```

But this query includes author's details in each post, which is duplicate also making response heavy.

Is there is any way to include only postAuther's objectId?

Answer (score 1):

you dont have to use 'query.include`

the `postAuthor` field will be a pointer, which includes the id (objectId) :

```
var Posts = Parse.Object.extend("Posts");
var query = new Parse.Query(Posts);
// filter as required
query.find().then (function (posts) {
   posts.forEach(function (post) {
      console.log('Authors objectId is ' + post.get('postAuthor').id
   })
})
```

Comment: But it makes response really heavy, I want few columns from 'Post'. 
and only 'id' for 'postAuthor', normally it gives all columns from 'user' table as well.

Comment: To limit the fields in 'Post', use the [Parse.query.select](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_select). If you haven't asked for the query to include the user, it wont . i.e, you must NOT have the line 'query.include("postAuthor");'